# How Sharepoint enables editing data via Excel?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, tcptrace-pocketsoap

a Sharepoint Web Query allows saving changed Excel cells back to the server. 
It's quite simple to come up with a custom JSP(or any other dynamic html producer) page to produce data called in QYI file. 
My question: is there a way to handle in a JSP page changes in the Excel List when "Synchronize with Server" menu clicked in Excel?
other words. How exactly Excel sends changes from the edited cell to the Sharepoint server?
I used TCP trace to see what Excel sends on "synchronize" but so far it did not make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft publishes the [Excel Services Publishing Protocol Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313039.aspx) under their [Microsoft Open Specification Promise](http://www.microsoft.com/interop/osp/default.mspx).

Comment: Thanks,

I guess, now i need to learn more about Sharepoint Lists, in particular, is there a way to implement a compatible lists on non-MS platform